# How to get a node's value for the key path of a property's property

Tags: swift, properties, key

I wish to get the value for the key path of a property's property, for example the value of `size.width` or `position.x` for an `SKSpriteNode`. If I have the following code in an `SKScene`, I get a runtime error on the last line:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode()
sprite.color = SKColor.red
sprite.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 320, y: 240)

self.addChild(sprite)
print(sprite.value(forKeyPath: "position")) //NSPoint: {320, 204}
print(sprite.value(forKeyPath: "size")) //NSSize: {50,50}
print(sprite.value(forKeyPath: "position.x")) //terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Is there any way of doing this in Swift 4? Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The following is another example of something that doesn't work:

```
class Object: NSObject {
    var foo : Foo = Foo()
}

class Foo : NSObject {
    var bar : Int = 0
}

let myObject = Object()
print(myObject.foo.bar) //0
print(myObject.value(forKeyPath: "foo.bar")) //terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I understand that I could do what @Eric has said for my first example:

```
print((sprite.value(forKeyPath: "position") as! CGPoint).x) //works fine
```

But this does not work in my second example:

```
print((myObject.value(forKeyPath: "foo") as! Foo).bar) //still terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This leads me to believing that is a '*hack*' which won't work all of the time, so I wish not to use it. Through more research on this topic I have came across this Objective C code, which shows that the whole point for value forKeyPath was to be able to get a property's property:

```
// Using nested valueForKey:
NSLog(@"%@", [[myObject valueForKey:@"foo"] valueForKey:@"bar"]);
// Can be done with a single valueForKeyPath;
NSLog(@"%@", [myObject valueForKeyPath:@"foo.bar"]);
```

If I were to convert that into swift I get this:

```
// Using nested valueForKey:
print(myObject.value(forKey: "foo").value(forKey: "bar")) //Error: value of 'Any?' has no member 'value'
// Can be done with a single valueForKeyPath;
print(myObject.value(forKeyPath: "foo.bar")) //terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Easy fix for the second line:

```
// Using nested valueForKey:
print((myObject.value(forKey: "foo") as! Foo).value(forKey: "bar")) //terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException       
// Can be done with a single valueForKeyPath;
print(myObject.value(forKeyPath: "foo.bar")) //also terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

But now they both show errors, this leads me to believe that this maybe value forKeyPath and value forKey were not properly implemented into swift. If anyone could offer a little bit of incite into all of this is would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the **EDIT** part.

All properties accessed through KVC (String-based keyPath uses KVC) needs to be exposed to Objective-C runtime. In Swift 4, you need to explicitly annotate with `@objc`.

```
class Object: NSObject {
    @objc var foo : Foo = Foo() //<-
}

class Foo : NSObject {
    @objc var bar : Int = 0 //<-
}

let myObject = Object()
print(myObject.foo.bar) //->0
print(myObject.value(forKeyPath: "foo.bar")) //->Optional(0)

print((myObject.value(forKey: "foo") as! Foo).value(forKey: "bar")) //->Optional(0)
print((myObject.value(forKeyPath: "foo") as! Foo).bar) //->0
```

---

About the original part.

Consider using [smart KeyPath](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0161-key-paths.md) of Swift 4.

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode()
sprite.color = SKColor.red
sprite.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 320, y: 240)

print(sprite[keyPath: \SKSpriteNode.position]) //->(320.0, 240.0)
print(sprite[keyPath: \SKSpriteNode.size]) //->(50.0, 50.0)
print(sprite[keyPath: \SKSpriteNode.position.x]) //->320.0
```

Smart KeyPath is not another notation of String-based keyPaths, so it cannot replace all use cases of KVC keyPaths. But it can work with non-Objective-C properties, which is very convenient in some cases.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. You have helped so much, thanks! This makes everything 10 times easier.

Comment: I have a question about these Smart KeyPaths, but I thought it was out of the scope of this question so I made a new one. You seem to be knowledgable about this, perhaps you could answer it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909769/smart-keypaths-in-swift-4-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

The last line won't work as it doesn't now on forehand that "position" is going to be a `NSPoint` with an `x` value. To make it work just cast the position as an `CGPoint/NSPoint` like so:

```
print((sprite.value(forKeyPath: "position") as! CGPoint).x)
```

However hard casting, what the explanation mark does, isn't an good idea as it will crash when the sprite doesn't have a position set so it's better to use:

```
if let position = sprite.value(forKeyPath: "position") as? CGPoint {
    print(position.x)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but while this does work in my example, it doesn't work in all cases, I have added an example where this does not work in an edit to my question